# Background color to highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, background-color

I have a requirement and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I need to have a background color to my chart but not labels in highcharts.
Is it possible, can anybody help me with this.

Sample link here for chart with a background color.

```
 chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
        type: 'line'
    },
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/backgroundcolor-color/)

But what I need is:

[image]

In this image the area which is covered in red section need to have no background color.

Comment: If you had just keep looking at the docs you would see that there is a [plotBackGroundColor option](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/plotbackgroundcolor-color/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the chart background color and the plot area background color separately:

```
chart: {
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  plotBackgroundColor: '#fcffc5'
}
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/cfrfjuvz/1/

Answer (score 1):

`.highcharts-plot-background` is what you are looking for. Add this to your **CSS**:

```
.highcharts-plot-background {
    fill: #FCFFC5;
}
.highcharts-plot-border {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: #7cb5ec;
}
```

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jooovkbh/).